# How to change the colour of KATE text editor's UI

Tags: kali-linux, kate

I have recently downloaded KATE text editor for my kali linux. I love the editor ,but the light UI is a real eyesore.

Does anybody know how to make the UI dark like the editor's theme?

[image: KATE example image]

Comment: On Ubuntu (related to Kali) Kate uses the desktop theme's window background colour. I don't know how to change this for individual programs that have not been coded to allow it, but maybe a darker background generally will suit you.

Comment: I already set kali to dark mode in the tweak settings, changing the theme there seems to have no effect on KATE

Comment: I set the window background colour in `Appearance Preferences` -> `Theme` -> `Customise` -> `Colours`, and Kate follows the theme, but I am running Kate in a KDE overlay to a Gnome-based system, so I can't test your environment.

Comment: I have the same issue. Switching the Ubuntu 22.04 theme to dark mode does only darken the top bar. As shown in the example pic above, some parts that are neither kate theme, nor Ubuntu dark mode stay bright. A right pain in the neck. Any other suggestions? On kate's landing page all is nice and dark themed so it somehow is possible .. https://kate-editor.org/ cheers

Answer (score 3):

In the menu, click Settings > Configure Kate...
In the sidebar menu of the popup, under "Editor Component" click "Fonts & Colors".
At the bottom of the panel where it says "Default schema for kate:", select from the dropdown...

On mine, I have options for things like vim (dark).
Click Apply and Ok.

Now when you restart kate, it will retain the default schema.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the questioner is not referring to the color scheme for the inner text editor as described in the other answers, but to the ui.

Depending on the operating system and installation you are using, you will not have any window themes available other than a light default theme. To get a set of dark themes, you can install kvantum for example. Below is an example of a minimal xfce installation.

Default(Light only)

[image]

vs.: after installing kvantum and restarting kate

Dark Themes

[image]

Comment: This is my first post in this community, so I have to link images until I am allowed to embed them.

Comment: The difference is between menu items `view > color themes` and `settings > color scheme` and this answer is for Kate's UI, the SCHEME not the editor. Glad someone actually read the question :) The package currently on Ubuntu variants is "qt5-style-kvantum-themes`  
This allows the application to change colors, theme, and have the menus, side panel etc in dark mode,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are able to change its theme, do the following...

1. Right click on the toolbar and select "Configure Toolbar"
2. Add the "Configure Kate" option
3. Click the "Configure Kate" widgets that now is on the toolbar.
4. Go to "Font & Coloring"
5. Select the schema that you want
6. Click "Apply" then "OK"
7. Done.

That's what I did and was able to change and customize the themes as I wanted.

Hope it helps.

[image]